# How do I create a selection with the caret at the start and the anchor at the end?

Tags: javascript

How do I create a selection with the caret at the start and the anchor at the end?

For example:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var el = document.getElementById("example");
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(el, 5);
range.setEnd(el, 8);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

places the anchor at offset=5 and the caret at offset=8 .

Setting `range.setEnd()` to a point before the start doesn't work (at least in Chrome).

So how do I do the reverse?

[I am replacing the outerHTML of the element containing the selection, and I want to preserve the selection exactly]

Answer (score 0):

Good question. `Selection.modify()` is the only thing I’ve been able to find so far:

```
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(el, 8);
range.setEnd(el, 8);

var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    sel.modify("extend", "left", "character");
}
```

Ugly, but it works. [Here’s a demo!](http://rninty.me/files/reverse-selection.html)

Comment: Works, but limited to "character", "word", etc. Painfully complicated if the node is different... if even possible.

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, you’d just have to keep going character by character, with some tree stuff. I’m already working on that for an editor of mine, so maybe I can get it done tonight :P

Answer (score 0):

I found that [selection.setBaseAndExtent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/setBaseAndExtent) works (at least in Chrome).

```js
//removeAllRanges(); is unnecessary.
sel.setBaseAndExtent(el, 5, el, 0);
```